# Training Neural Networks on Hadoop Cluster

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, neural-network, keras

I have been studying neural networks for some weeks. Furthermore even if I always used R the *Keras* library in *Python* was really helpful with someone with a **small programming background like me**.

**Keras** it's a very nice interface which **allows the customization** I need without even invoking the backend, unless for some custom loss metrics I used.

Being that straightforward is also the **Hardware specification**, which for example **allows you to switch from the CPU** of the machine where you have your Python+Keras installed **to** the machine **(compatible) GPU**, **allowing to exploit the strong parallelization of neural networks when training them**.

**I was wondering if there is anything which allows you to switch to hadoop cluster training of neural networks with the same kind of ease.
Moreover is there some hadoop open source cluster available to do so?**

Thank you for your help

Comment: Found something: https://databricks.com/blog/2017/02/09/intels-bigdl-databricks.html

Comment: Take a look to [distributed keras](https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/blog/joeri-hermans/2017-01-distributed-deep-learning-apache-spark-and-keras) on spark from Cern. [Here's an example](https://github.com/cerndb/dist-keras/blob/master/examples/mnist.ipynb)

Comment: Thank you @prudenko ! 

I'll leave the question for a complete answer that may help everybody :)

Comment: Apparently Cloudera has created a tool called [Data Science Workbench](https://www.cloudera.com/products/data-science-and-engineering/data-science-workbench.html) which promises to integrate with a lot of deep learning libraries. Haven't worked with it, but it seems promising.